# the meaning of 'pull oneself up' here

Tags: phrase-meaning

The following is from The African Queen by C. S. Forester

> Yet even as the hot wave of fervour swept over her, she **pulled
>   herself up** with scorn of herself for daydreaming. Here she was alone
>   in the Central African forest, alone with a dead man. There was no
>   possible chance of her achieving anything.

Does the bold mean '**rebuke** herself'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is just a continuation of the "wave" metaphor. The wave (like an ocean wave) breaks over her and she goes underwater. She *pulls herself up* from beneath this wave (as you do with your arms underwater) and returns to the surface of practical reality.

Comment: My initial understanding was something along that line and then, unfortunately, I looked up the dictionary and there was another meaning, 'rebuke.'  All of sudden I wasn't sure of it anymore. Thank you for clarifying it.

Answer (score -1):

She stopped herself from having those thoughts / emotions / daydreams.

The metaphor is to pull on the reigns of a horse to make it stop.